# ATMEGA1284p and RFM95 sleep current around 35µA: can it be reduced further?

Tags: atmega, low-power, atmel, atmega328p, power-consumption

In my project, I am using an ATMEGA1284p processor in the TQFP-44_10.0x10.0x0.8P package as well as a RFM95 LoRa module.

For the low-power mode, I'm using the rocket scream low-power library: https://github.com/rocketscream/Low-Power
The bootloader comes from maniacbug: https://github.com/maniacbug/mighty-1284p

I've measured a sleep current of around 35µA (300mAh LiPo connected).

The RF95 module is configured to sleep, where it should consume less than 1.5µA.

As clock, I use a 16MHz external one: Yangxing Tech X322516MLB4SI

VDD and GND from the LiPo are delivered to the ATMEGA1284p and the RF95 module continuously, there is no power circuit.

Where should I look at to further reduce the sleep current?

Resources:

- [ATMEGA1284p datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc8059.pdf)
- [RF95 LoRra datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/8/0/4/RFM95_96_97_98W.pdf)
- [LoRa LMIC library](https://github.com/matthijskooijman/arduino-lmic)

EDIT: I have eventually found the source for the current consumption, just two voltage dividers, one connected to 'a potential sensor source' and one to VCC. The one connected to VCC should draw around 13µA (320kOhm, 3.9-4V LiPo supply when fully charged).

I'll try the following steps:

1. remove the voltage divider connected to the LiPo battery
2. Configure the input pin for the generic sensor input as output
3. remove also the second voltage divider

Comment: how did you measured 35µA and how sure are you about the accuracy?

Comment: @asim I've checked with two multimeters, one for USB logging and a standard one. The standard one was Tacklife DM01M in 60µA mode and the logging one was Bolyfa117, I ended up with the same values.

Comment: it might help you if you can measure them separately

Comment: Unused unconnected pins configured as inputs can draw excess current when they float near the half-way point. Pull them one way or the other, or if unconnected, configure them as outputs.

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the RFM95 to make sure it’s actually consuming what you think it should? Just to isolate which one of the two is drawing power...